# AlchemyAPI gives an error when compiling

Tags: python, alchemyapi, pyxml

I'm trying out AlchemyAPI_Python-0.6 - PyXml module. I was trying to run the keyword extractor feature of it, but got the following error when trying to compile. I used the keywords.py file given in the examples. I copied all the files underneath the python directory (AlchemyAPI.py, keywords.py, api_key.txt).

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python26\keywords.py", line 4, in <module>
    import AlchemyAPI
  File "C:\Python26\AlchemyAPI.py", line 6, in <module>
    from xml import xpath
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\_xmlplus\xpath\__init__.py", line 112, in <module>
    from pyxpath import ExprParserFactory
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\_xmlplus\xpath\pyxpath.py", line 59, in <module>
    from xml.xpath.ParsedAbbreviatedRelativeLocationPath import ParsedAbbreviatedRelativeLocationPath
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\_xmlplus\xpath\ParsedAbbreviatedRelativeLocationPath.py", line 31
    as = ParsedAxisSpecifier.ParsedAxisSpecifier('descendant-or-self')
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Can some one help me out with this issue, please?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I work for AlchemyAPI.

We just revamped our Python SDK, removing dependencies on PyXML (if you're using Python 2.4 and earlier, you'll need lxml).

Please find the new SDK here:  http://www.alchemyapi.com/tools/

It supports all versions of Python 2 and Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

PyXML was written for Python 2.4, and the `as` keyword was introduced gradually in Python 2.5 and 2.6. In the last line of the stack trace above, the `as` keyword is used as a variable name, which conflicts with the syntax of Python 2.6.

You can solve this issue by editing two files, changing the name of the `as` variable to something else (e.g. `axis`):

- `C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\_xmlplus\xpath\ParsedAbbreviatedRelativeLocationPath.py`, lines 31 and 32:

  ```
  axis = ParsedAxisSpecifier.ParsedAxisSpecifier('descendant-or-self')
  self._middle = ParsedStep.ParsedStep(axis, nt, ppl)
  ```
- `C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\_xmlplus\xpath\ParsedAbbreviatedAbsoluteLocationPath.py`, lines 27 and 28:

  ```
  axis = ParsedAxisSpecifier.ParsedAxisSpecifier('descendant-or-self')
  self._step = ParsedStep.ParsedStep(axis, nt, ppl)
  ```